# responsive logo over carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

[this is my 1st page where logo and carousel both are in the top section of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwMHQ.jpg)I was trying to put a responsive logo over carouser from bootstrap. Logo was over the carousel but it does not shows the responsive behavior. I used the code from www.w3schools.com i think its somewhere in the carousel class in bootstrap.min.css but cant locate it. If someone has work on it plz leave the comment. 
html:

```
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->

         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">         </li>
           <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>


           <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
               <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="overlay">
                   <!--<img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">-->
               </div>
                 <div class="item active">
                 <img src="images/1bg.jpg" alt="">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    </div>
                     </div>
                 <div class="item">
              <img src="images/11bg.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="carousel-caption">
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
               <img src="images/111bg.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="carousel-caption">
               </div>
               </div>
               <!-- Left and right controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                       <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                      </div>


         </div>
       </div>
```

logo is in overlay div.I want logo to be responsive

```
                .overlay {background: url('../images/logo.png') top left  no- repeat;position: absolute;top: 30px;
           left: 600px;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 10;pointer-events: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Use percentage instead of pixel in overlay class.* 
**For Example:**

```
 .overlay {background: url('../images/logo.png') top left  no- repeat;position: absolute;top: 3%;left: 50%;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 10;pointer-events: none;}
```

> change top and left percentages value as you need.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried giving percentages values but it does not make logo responsive

Comment: Try to to add **background-size:100% auto;**

Comment: @ shaddam    __adding background-size:100% auto;__
that just make the logo full size which is over the carousel